# Gnome Calendar not working in Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, 22.04, google, gnome-calendar

Everything was totally fine when I used Ubuntu 21.10. But after I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome Calendar stopped to sync my events of my Google accounts. I was not getting anything at first but then, I purged it and reinstalled it. Then connected my Google accounts again in gnome-online-accounts (goa). Then I launched the app from terminal and I found the issue. It's showing,

```
    soumyaxubuntu@soumyas-HP-Laptop-15-bs164tu ~ [1]> gnome-calendar

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.850: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Christian Holidays': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.850: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Class 8 Sutavra none': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.850: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Contacts': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.850: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Drik Panchang': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.851: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Hindu Holidays': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.851: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Holidays in India': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.851: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Muslim Holidays': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.851: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'Orthodox Holidays': Timeout was reached

(gnome-calendar:23122): GcalManager-WARNING **: 19:08:16.851: source_credentials_required_cb: Failed to authenticate 'ri*******67@gmail.com': Timeout was reached
```

I am getting no fix of it. I have tried multiple times. Any fix of this???? Also, when I tried to use app password as I have 2fa on, goa forces me to use the password of my Google account. I have tried the v42 of calendar in Fedora and it works fine.

Comment: It is the same in Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS x86_64 - same warnings, but calendar seems to work, and events are synced from google account.